# I wrote a mini-project in c. The code is compiled well, but it does not run well

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

The project is composed of five excersices:
ex1) ordering an array, so that the odd values will appear in the start, and then the even values.
ex2) checking if a number devides by 11
ex3) finding the intersection array (and its size) of two unsorted arrays.
ex4) checking if two arrays are permutation of each other.
ex5 getting a string and a char, and removing that char from the string.

**Tt's seems that ex3 and ex4 are not running well, and I cant understand why.**

Here is the code:

```
        #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

void Ex1();
void Ex2();
void Ex3();
void Ex4();
void Ex5();
void merge_sort(int *a,int first, int last);
void merge(int *a, int p, int q, int r);
int *input_array_dyn(int n);
char* input_long();
void swap(int* a, int* b);
void PrintArray(int arr[], int size);
void ParityOfArray(int arr[], int size);
int SumOfDigits(int num);
int IsDividesBy11(int num);
int* IntersectionOfArrays(int* arr1, int size1, int* arr2, int size2, int* sizeRes);
int CheckPermutation1(int arr1[], int arr2[], int size);
int CheckPermutation2(int arr1[], int arr2[], int size);
int CheckPermutation3(int arr1[], int arr2[], int size);
void removeChar(char str[], char ch);


void main()
{

    int select, fcontinue=1;

    while (fcontinue==1)
    {
        printf ("please enter numbers 1-5 to choose excercise , or 0 to exit\n");
        scanf ("%d", &select);

        switch (select) 
        {
        case 1: Ex1(); break;
        case 2: Ex2(); break;
        case 3: Ex3(); break;
        case 4: Ex4(); break;
        case 5: Ex5(); break;
        case 0: fcontinue=0; break;
        default: printf ("invalid option, try again\n");
        } 
    }

}

void Ex1()
{
    int *arr, size;

    printf ("enter the size of the array: ");
    scanf ("%d", &size);
    printf("\n");

    arr=input_array_dyn(size);
    ParityOfArray(arr, size);
    printf("\n the array after the change: ");
    PrintArray(arr, size);
    printf("\n");

    free(arr);

}

void Ex2()
{
    int num;

    printf ("enter a non-negative, integer number \n");
    scanf ("%d",&num);

    if (IsDividesBy11(num)==1) 
        printf("%d divides by 11\n", num);
    else
        printf("%d does not divide by 11\n", num);

}

void Ex3()
{
    int *arr1, *arr2, *res;
    int size1,size2,sizeRes;

    printf("array number 1: ");
    printf ("enter the size of the array: ");
    scanf ("%d", &size1);
    printf("\n");
    arr1=input_array_dyn(size1);
    printf("\n array number 2: ");
    printf ("enter the size of the array: ");
    scanf ("%d", &size2);
    printf("\n");
    arr2=input_array_dyn(size2);
    printf("\n");

    res=IntersectionOfArrays(arr1, size1, arr2, size2, &sizeRes);
    printf("the intersection of the arrays is: ");
    PrintArray(res, sizeRes);
    printf(" and the size of the intersection is %d\n", sizeRes);

    free(res);
    free(arr2);
    free(arr1);

}

void Ex4()
{
    int *arr1, *arr2;
    int size;

    printf ("solutin number 1 (non-recursive): \n enter the size of two arrays (same size): ");
    scanf ("%d", &size);
    printf("\n");
    arr1=input_array_dyn(size);
    printf("\n");
    arr2=input_array_dyn(size);
    printf("\n");
    if (CheckPermutation1(arr1,  arr2, size)==1)
        printf("these arrays are permutation of each other\n");
    else 
        printf("these arrays are not permutation of each other\n");

    printf ("solutin number 2 (recursive): \n enter the size of two arrays (same size): ");
    scanf ("%d", &size);
    printf("\n");
    arr1=input_array_dyn(size);
    printf("\n");
    arr2=input_array_dyn(size);
    printf("\n");
    if (CheckPermutation2(arr1,  arr2, size)==1)
        printf("these arrays are permutation of each other\n");
    else 
        printf("these arrays are not permutation of each other\n");

    printf ("solutin number 1 (values from 1 to 100!): \n enter the size of two arrays (same size): ");
    scanf ("%d", &size);
    printf("\n");
    arr1=input_array_dyn(size);
    printf("\n");
    arr1=input_array_dyn(size);
    printf("\n");
    if (CheckPermutation3(arr1,  arr2, size)==1)
        printf("these arrays are permutation of each other\n");
    else 
        printf("these arrays are not permutation of each other\n");
    free(arr1);
    free(arr2);

}

void Ex5()
{
    char *str, ch;

    str=input_long();
    printf("\n please enter a char to be removed from the string ");
    scanf("%c", &ch);

    removeChar(str, ch);
    printf("\n the string after the removal is %s \n", str);

    free(str);
}

void ParityOfArray(int arr[], int size) 
{
    int i = 0, j = size - 1;

    while (i < j)
    {
        if ((arr[i] % 2) != 0) 
            i++;
        else if ((arr[j] % 2) == 0)
            j--;
        else 
        {
            swap (&arr[i],&arr[j]);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
}

int SumOfDigits(int num) 
{
    int digit1, digit2;

    if (num < 10) 
        return num;
    else 
    {
        digit1 = num % 10;
        num /= 10;
        digit2 = num % 10;
        return digit1 - digit2 + SumOfDigits(num / 10);
    }
}

int IsDividesBy11(int num) 
{
    int sum=SumOfDigits(num);

    while (sum>=10)
        sum=abs(SumOfDigits(sum));
    if (sum==0)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int* IntersectionOfArrays(int* arr1, int size1, int* arr2, int size2, int* sizeRes) 
{
    int* res=(int*)malloc(1*sizeof(int));
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    *sizeRes = 0;

    merge_sort(arr1,0, size1 -1);
    merge_sort(arr2,0, size2 -1);

    while (i < size1 && j < size2) 
    {
        if (arr1[i] < arr2[j])
            i++;
        else if (arr1[i] > arr2[j]) 
            j++;
        else 
        {   res[*sizeRes] = arr1[i];
        i++;
        j++;
        *sizeRes++;
        res = (int*)realloc(res, 1*sizeof(int));
        }   
    }

    if (*sizeRes==0)
        return NULL;
    return res;
}

void removeChar(char str[], char ch) 
{
    int i,j = 0;
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] != ch)
        {
            str[j] = str[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    str[j]='\0';
}

int CheckPermutation1(int arr1[], int arr2[], int size)
{
    int i;

    merge_sort(arr1,0, size -1);
    merge_sort(arr2,0, size -1);

    for (i=0;i<size;i++)
        if (arr1[i]!=arr2[i])
            return 1;
    return 0;
}

int CheckPermutation2(int arr1[], int arr2[], int size)
{
    int i; 

    if (size == 0) 
        return 1;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        if (arr2[i] == arr1[0]) 
        {
            swap(&arr2[0],&arr2[i]);
            return CheckPermutation2(arr1 + 1, arr2 + 1, size - 1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int CheckPermutation3(int arr1[], int arr2[], int size)
{
    int count[100];
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
        count[i]=0;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        count[arr1[i]]++;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        count[arr2[i]]--;
    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
        if (count[i]!=0)
            return 0;
    return 1;
}

void merge_sort(int *a,int first, int last)
{
    int middle;
    if(first < last)
    {
        middle=(first+last)/2;
        merge_sort(a, first, middle);
        merge_sort(a, middle+1, last);
        merge(a, first, middle, last);
    }
}

void merge(int *a, int p, int q, int r)
{
    int i=p, j=q+1, k=0;
    int* temp=(int*)malloc((r-p+1) * sizeof(int));
    while ((i<=q) && (j<=r))
        if(a[i] < a[j])
            temp[k++] = a[i++];
        else
            temp[k++] = a[j++];
    while(j<=r) // if( i>q )
        temp[k++]=a[j++];
    while(i<=q) // j>r
        temp[k++]=a[i++];
    for(i=p,k=0; i<=r; i++,k++) // copy temp[] to a[]
        a[i]=temp[k];
    free(temp);
}

int *input_array_dyn(int n)
{
    int i;
    int *arr;

    arr=(int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
    assert(arr); /* calloc() worked */
    printf("enter the array of length %d\n",n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) 
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);

    return arr;
}

char* input_long()
{
    char tempstr[80], *longnum;

    printf("enter a string\n");
    flushall();
    gets(tempstr);
    longnum=(char*)malloc((strlen(tempstr)+1)*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(longnum,tempstr);

    return longnum;
}

void swap(int* a, int* b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

void PrintArray(int arr[], int size)
{
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! "Not running well" isn't a great description of a problem. What exactly happens? Consider reading [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Don't use `gets`, and what's `flushall()`, it is a Microsoft thing?

Comment: Debugging can be hard, but learning to use a debugger to find these hard problems, is the best learning moment this excercise can bring you! I encourage you to use a debugger (and everyone else: only give hints and no solutions, please).

Comment: SO isn't a debugging service. Compile with symbols, run the code inside a debugger to trace through the program(s) line by line inspecting the values of the relevant variables to learn what is really going on. If then a *specific* question arises feel free to come back here.

Comment: you state the code 'compiles well'.  Actually, it does not.  For instance, function `input_long()` has no prototype.  The function: flushall() has no prototype,  the function: `gets()` is depreciated (and compiletely removed in the latest C standard) .   When writing prototypes that have no parameters, always place `void` between the parens otherwise the compiler will produced code for 'any number' of parameters,rather than no parameters.

Comment: regardless of what the visual studio app will let you get away with, there are only a few valid signatures for the function `main()` and they all have a return type of `int`

Comment: when calling any of the heap memory functions: 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful  2) when calling `realloc()`, do not directly assign the returned value to the target pointer without first checking (!=NULL)  otherwise when the function fails, the original pointer is lost, resulting in a memory leak.  3) the returned type is `void*` so can be assigned to any other pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.

Comment: consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: what is `flushall()`  perhaps you meant `fflush(stdout)`.   Note: `fflush()` is for output streams only.  For input streams, use a loop, reading byte by byte until some terminator (like '\n') or EOF

Comment: when calling any of the heap memory allocation functions, the expression: `sizeof(char)` just clutters the code.  The C standard defines that expression as always 1 and multiplying by 1 has absolutely no effect.

Comment: in function: `input_long()` strongly suggest you learn about an use either `readline()` or `getline()`

Comment: when working with numbers that will NEVER be <0, strongly suggest using `size_t` rather than `int`

Comment: this statement: `*sizeRes++;` has a problem.  Specifically, in C, the precedence of operators will result in the pointer being incremented rather than the place where the pointer points.  Suggest: `(*sizeRes)++;`

Comment: I am forced to used  input_long(). As to (*sizeRes)++   , it still dont work...